# pull data from multiple tables in one query and matching data together

Tags: php, sql

OK I have two sql tables I need to query from which are `product` and `product_to_category`

`product` looks like

[image]

`product_to_category` looks like

[image]

I am trying to query both the tables so that I can select all that are in a certain category number, which is in `product_to_category`, but also select all that have a status of 1, which determines if they are active or not. I am trying to do this in a single query, and so far my query looks like what is below, problem is that I am not sure how to match the `product_id`'s together to work how I would like. Can someone give me an idea of how to do this?

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product,product_to_category WHERE product.status = 1 AND product_to_category.category_id = 35 ORDER BY product.sort_order ASC")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product JOIN product_to_category ON (product.product_id = product_to_category.product_id) WHERE product.status = 1 AND product_to_category.category_id = 35 ORDER BY product.sort_order ASC")`

Comment: Thanks, this helped out a ton, I have never heard of JOIN before.

Answer (score 2):

you should use a JOIN

`SELECT * 
FROM product p
INNER JOIN product_to_category pc
    ON p.productid = pc.productid 
WHERE p.status = 1 
    AND pc.category_id = 35 
ORDER BY p.sort_order ASC`

since you are not familiar with joins, I suggest reading the following:

A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins:

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Comment: Thanks, this helped out a ton, I have never heard of JOIN before.

Comment: Since you have not heard of JOINs before I suggest using http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html to help learn them.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM product
INNER JOIN product_to_category ON (product.product_id = product_to_category.product_id)
WHERE 
     product_to_category.category_id = 35
     AND
     product.status = 1
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped out a ton, I have never heard of JOIN before.

Answer (score 1):

Try following query. It is easier to comprehend

```
SELECT * FROM 
    product a
    JOIN product_to_category b ON a.product_id = b.product_id
WHERE 
    a.stock_status_id = 1
    AND b.category_id = 35;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product p LEFT JOIN product_to_category pc ON (p.id = pc.product_id) WHERE p.status = 1 AND pc.category_id = 35 ORDER BY p.sort_order ASC");
```

This should do the trick. Make sure you look in to JOINS and their different types